# Drawing multiple bitmaps in just one texture

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash

I have a series of pictures each is 128*128. The number of pictures are 36. 
I would like to group them in one picture, so that they are drawn like that:

```
public static const SIZE : int 1024;
public var img1 : Bitmap;
public var img2 : Bitmap;

var bmp:BitmapData=new BitmapData(SIZE,SIZE,false,0);

//Draw img1 at 0,0
bmp.draw(img1); 

//Draw img2 at 512,0
bmp.draw(img2, new Matrix(1,0,0,1, SIZE/2, 0)); 

//Draw img1 at 512,512
bmp.draw(img1, new Matrix(1,0,0,1, SIZE/2, SIZE/2)); 

//Draw img1 at 0,512
bmp.draw(img2, new Matrix(1,0,0,1, 0, SIZE/2));
```

My problem is I would like to come up with an algorithm to place the images regardless the numbers, so that I don't create an image  by static codes.. A Pseudo code it helps if you can't get it using AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var images:Vector.<Bitmap> = new Vector.<Bitmap>();
images[0] = bmp1;
images[1] = bmp2;
// etc...

var i:int = 0;
var l:int = images.length;
var maxWidth :int = 0;
var totalHeight:int = 0;
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
var render:Bitmap; // your final render


// find how tall will be the picture:
for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth , images[i].width); // find the widest image
    totalHeight += images[i].height; // find the total height of your image
}

// create the render container based on the data we just found out:
render = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( maxWidth , totalHeight, true, 0xff00ff ) );

// draw!
for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    render.bitmapData.daw(images[i], mat);
    matrix.translate(0, images[i].height);
}
```

I couldn't test it but it should work, or at least get you on the right direction. Let me know!

Comment: thanks it worked, but they are down horizontally to each other, how can I make them vertically?.  I liked the idea of the total height accumulation :). The final image should be a power of two, the width and the height, so I modified the final height and width to be a power of two. How would I also rotate the bitmaps 90degree before drawing them to the large texture ?

Comment: You need to mess around to understand better how the matrix alter the position. Look into matrix.rotate(). Another way could be to create a regular display Sprite, addChild as many images as you have on it, rotate and place the images and draw the sprite instead of the image.

Comment: would you please elaborate the sprite solution ?

Comment: add all your images as child to a display object (sprite) just like you would place them on stage. Then draw the sprite at once. bitmapData.draw(spriteContainer);

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to copy the smaller images to the larger image, starting at the top and moving to the right, and moving down to the next row when the top row is full.

So, assuming that you have a BigImage that you want to fill, and an array of SmallImages that you want to put in it, the algorithm looks something like:

```
xpos = 0
ypos = 0
for i = 0 to number_of_small_images-1
    draw SmallImages[i] on BigImage at position (xpos, ypos)
    xpos += small_image_width
    if (xpos >= big_image_width)
        xpos = 0
        ypos = ypos + small_image_height
```

That's the basic idea. You'll have to flesh out the code in whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: I want them to be one down by one, like a reel of pictures.

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to supply some feedback. Is there something in particular you find wrong with this answer?

Comment: @JimMischel I'm the one who downvoted your reply. I don't think it help his issue much and I provided a clearer explanation I believe. No offense but this was an AS3 question.